# TIBCO Rendezvous Publisher and Subscriber Programs

Tags: tibco

I'm looking to write a basic publisher and basic subscriber program using TIBCO Rendezvous for an assignment. However, I'm not familiar with Rendezvous and the documentation i got was mostly a long list of concepts and functions with almost no code.

I was wondering if anyone knows of any tutorials that have code samples or tutorials for writing small programs, so I can see some code and understand how this thing works.

If not I would appreciate any advice on how to actually code either of these problems using rendezvous

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Rendezvous within TIBCO Businessworks?

Answer (score 3):

If you have installed Rendezvous then there are a number of examples in the installation directory. Look for "src/examples".